# Alias for File Manager

Tags: file-manager

I'm writing a script to use as a button on a personal toolbar.

Well, I'd like to know if there is a generic command to call the file manager which would work in any distro (or maybe in any ubuntu derived distro).

For example:

1. on Ubuntu I'd call `nautilus`
2. on Lubuntu I'd call `pcmanfm`
3. on Xubuntu I'd call (`thunar`?)

But I'd like to simply use a general command, for example, `filemanager`.

Is it possible?

Comment: This is a user preference, it has nothing to do with the distribution.

Comment: @Gilles, so the solution given below could work with any distro?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Passing [xdg-open](http://man.cx/xdg-open) a directory name should open the file manager:

```
xdg-open ~/
```

Comment: This is likely the best solution, but the distributed nature of *nix means that this solution still isn't a sure thing. It will only work if the user has a file manager of which `xdg-open` is aware.